# Installing Python packages using pip in Windows command propmt

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, spyder

I am trying to install some Python packages using pip install from Windows command prompt. Which directory should I go to for installing the packages? The pip install operation ends quite swiftly, without showing any statements such as 'fetching' or 'in progress' or 'completed' or any such indication, and the Spyder shell I am working in shows the 'No module named xxx' error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of installing packages in in root directory but you can install them anywhere you want. Check your network connection as this can happen because of bad network connections.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you dont have multiple python version installed,you can do that by runing

```
python --version
```

and also make sure you are in correct in env.

> This highlights a key difference between conda and pip. Pip installs
> Python packages whereas conda installs packages which may contain
> software written in any language. For example, before using pip, a
> Python interpreter must be installed via a system package manager or
> by downloading and running an installer. Conda on the other hand can
> install Python packages as well as the Python interpreter directly.

so make sure you using right tool and also check your internet connectivity.(@Divyessh Maheshwari)

similar thread:[Pip install in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963625/pip-install-in-spyder)