# I am brand new to Python and Spyder. When I type 'pip list' or any other command into the console it returns an error

Tags: python, spyder

I am brand new to Python/Spyder. When I type `pip list` into the console it returns this error:

`Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages. 'C:\Users is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I am running Windows 10, I have tried changing the path in environment variables and within Spyder itself with no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip install in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963625/pip-install-in-spyder)